# Display degree symbol in Arduino OLED

Tags: c, arduino

To display degree symbol to plot on OLED you can use

display.print((char)247); // degree symbol

example:

void loop(void){

```
display.setTextSize(1);
display.setTextColor(WHITE);
display.setCursor(0,0);
display.clearDisplay();

display.print("Temperature: ");
display.print("23");
display.print((char)247); // degree symbol 
display.println("C");
display.display();
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: it is unclear what your question is

Comment: Since this is my first contribution in stackoverflow, I think I did it wrong. 
The purpose was to post a useful answer initially not a question. I've seen this question in internet a lot with wrong char numbers and/or complicated solutions. This is a working tested option to plot a char on OLED using its code.

Comment: @HaykMartirosyan - Perhaps the first hint you were doing it wrong was the BIG BLUE BUTTON that says **Ask Question**. If you delete this post, you'll recoup the points lost to down-votes. Search for someone asking such a question then put all of this into the box labelled **Your Answer** ;)

Comment: @enhzfep, thanks! Yes you are right! Makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library/using-fonts) says:

> Each filename starts with the face name (“FreeMono”, “FreeSerif”, etc.) followed by the style (“Bold”, “Oblique”, none, etc.), font size in points (currently 9, 12, 18 and 24 point sizes are provided) and “7b” to indicate that these contain 7-bit characters (ASCII codes “ ” through “~”); *8-bit fonts (supporting symbols and/or international characters) are not yet provided but may come later*.

In other words, the degree symbol (U+00B0, `°`) is not supported by the fonts by default.

Of course, nothing stops you from redefining one of them as the degree symbol in the .h file that corresponds to the font you wish to use -- in particular, to make a copy of the existing file, renaming the copy, and replace one of the ASCII characters you do not need with the degree symbol. I would suggest replacing ` (ASCII code 96), because it is very similar to the more commonly used apostrophe ' (ASCII code 39).

An easier option is to just draw a small circle (say, radius 1, 2, or 3 pixels) at the correct position using `display.drawCircle(xcenter, ycenter, radius, WHITE);`. After all, the degree glyph is just a small circle -- consider the looks of e.g. 25°C or 77°F.

For more complex glyphs, if you don't want to create your own font .h files, you can use the `display.drawBitmap()` interface. Examine and experiment with [the Adafruit example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/master/examples/ssd1306_128x32_i2c/ssd1306_128x32_i2c.ino) for details.

You can use the [image2cpp](http://javl.github.io/image2cpp/) web page at GitHub to generate the Arduino data array. It also supports font format, so you can use that to generate the data for your degree symbol glyph, just by "drawing" it on that page.

Comment: I know this option. But what I wrote works just perfect on any oled I've tried.